Unable to present a sheet in SwiftUI: Attempt to present .... while a presentation is in progress
im working on a codebase were one of the sheets is centralized, its code is as follow:
import SwiftUI

struct CurrentTabKey: EnvironmentKey {
  static let defaultValue: Binding<MainTabView.TabItem> = .constant(.home)
}

struct PresentedSheetKey: EnvironmentKey {
  static let defaultValue: Binding<PresentedSheet?> = .constant(nil)
}

struct PresentedFullscreenKey: EnvironmentKey {
  static let defaultValue: Binding<PresentedFullscreen?> = .constant(nil)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
  var currentTab: Binding<MainTabView.TabItem> {
    get { self[CurrentTabKey.self] }
    set { self[CurrentTabKey.self] = newValue }
  }

  var presentedSheet: Binding<PresentedSheet?> {
    get { self[PresentedSheetKey.self] }
    set { self[PresentedSheetKey.self] = newValue }
  }

  var presentedFullscreen: Binding<PresentedFullscreen?> {
    get { self[PresentedFullscreenKey.self] }
    set { self[PresentedFullscreenKey.self] = newValue }
  }
}

also the display of that sheet is in the tabbar class as follow:
Router class:
   class AppRouter: ObservableObject {
      @Published var navPath = NavigationPath()
      @Published var presentedSheet: PresentedSheet?
      @Published var presentedFullscreen: PresentedFullscreen?
      @Published var selectedTab: MainTabView.TabItem = .home {
        didSet {
          if oldValue != .create {
            previouslySelectedTab = oldValue
          }
        }
      }
      @Published var previouslySelectedTab: MainTabView.TabItem = .home
      @Published var mainRouter = MainRouter()
    }

Tabbar View:
  .sheet(item: $appRouter.presentedSheet) { presentedSheet in
          view(presentedSheet: presentedSheet)
        }
    

  @ViewBuilder private func view(presentedSheet: PresentedSheet) -> some View {
    switch presentedSheet {
    case .authView:
      AuthenticationStateSheet(shouldRefresh: true)
    }
  }

When attempting to open the sheet in one of the tabbar views as follow:
 @Environment(\.presentedSheet) var presentedSheet
...
   presentedSheet.wrappedValue = .authView

it opens and closes automatically the first time, with the following error:
Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x105867e00> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x10580e400> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerVS_14_ViewList_View_: 0x1070a0c00>) while a presentation is in progress.

I tried to add breakpoints everywhere this sheet is been displayed and dismissed, but couldn't track any unexpected behaviors.
any help would be great

All that means is that there is another sheet, alert or something else already presenting at the same place that the sheet wants to present

You should not centralise sheets and full screen covers into a AppRouter like this. Where the sheet modifier is located is very important. This sort of log message is what you get when you e.g. try to present a sheet on top of a full screen cover or another sheet, but the sheet modifier is placed at an ancestor of the already-presented sheet/full screen cover.

yep, totally agree, but its not my codebase.
and yes but the issue is that im still not able to track whats been presented in the same place.

The problem here was that it was in a For loop, without noticing it.
so it was called multiple times, which caused the display problem.
